# How do I upgrade Filecoin Lotus to the latest version?

Tags: upgrade, decentralized-applications, filecoin, filecoin-lotus

I'm running a Lotus daemon and a new release was pushed to master. How do I upgrade to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop your daemon, then download the latest version:

`git pull master`

Then:

`make clean && make all`

Once that completes:

`sudo make install`

Now when you restart your daemon it should be on the latest version. To verify, run:

`lotus --version`

Comment: if your chain is synced `make clean` should not delete it. Once you install the new version it'll continue syncing where the old version left off.